# for k in data:how to reach k+1 in data in this loop

Tags: python

How can I reach the k+1 object in this loop? 
Is there a way in python like in java or c like `for(i=0;...)`?

```
for k in data:
 k+1
```

Comment: what type of data structure belongs `data`?, is it a `list` or `dictionary` or `tuple` or anything else?

Comment: I think you should go over some tutorials before coming here (no offense). You are asking about very basic stuff. You can use the [`range(len(data))`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) construct, or use the built-in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function

Comment: Note in the existing answers so far, they all assume that there *is* a next item, that is, that `k` isn't the last item from the iterator. (I don't want to have to comment on each answer individually.)

Comment: (They also assume that `data` is indexible, which isn't necessarily true for all iterables.)

Comment: You may now think about accepting an answer or comment one to get details ;) to reward those who spent time for you ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate using indices, not objects like

```
for i in range(len(data)-1):
    current = data[i]
    next_one = date[i+1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `enumerate`.

```
for idx,val in enumerate(data[:-1]):
    curr=val
    next_item=data[idx+1]
```